# CiviCRM permissions to only view basic reports

Tags: civicontribute

I am working with CiviCRM now for some 5 years. Currently with CiviCRM 4.7.19 integrated in Drupal 7.

I am trying to setup reports and permissions in such a way that a group of people can view and edit contacts, but not edit contributions.

I am unable to setup permissions to accomplish this. The problem is I can have this group of people access the participant reports but when they click on the contact name it wants to show the contact overview page and they would not have permission for that.
For some reason it seems I need to enable 'Access CiviContribute' (a way to broad permission!) in order to be able (in for instance the participant detail report) to click on the contact name and go to the contact detail page.

Is there another solution? Or am I doing things incorrectly? Of course I know views might be a way out, but I am trying to do this in CiviCRM.